# ms-access trying put variable into textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

Sorry guys, hello again.  Not a programmer, trying to muddle through something.

I got my search record thing working.

```
Dim Date1 As String
Dim Shift1 As String
Date1 = Text6.Value
Shift1 = List12.Column(1)
DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , "Data![ShiftDate] = #" & Date1 & _
"# AND Data![Shift] ='" & Shift1 & "'"
```

The new complication is now for when it opens up a new record because the criteria is not met.  When a record isnt found, I want it to force the two variables that were used to search into the shiftdate and shift fields.  This way I can lock down those fields and restrict my users from making a billion of the same date and shift.  It will either always direct them to the currently created one, or create the new one if its not available.

I tried

```
Data![shiftdate].Value = Date1
```

So that every time it found a record or created a new one, it matched the date to it.  Probably not the most efficient, but it should do what i need.  However, I am getting a **424 error code** amongst other problems.  Anyone know why it wont accept my input into the field on the found/created record?

Comment: You can pass the values in the OpenArgs parameter of OpenForm. When the form opens and loads you can check to see if Me.NewRecord is true and if so parse the OpenArgs values and assign them to your two locked textboxes

Answer (score 1):

Simply test + check if the record exists, and then open the form to the record, or simply open the form in add mode.

This should do the trick:

```
Dim strWhere      As String
Dim Date1         As String
Dim Shift1        As String

Date1 = Test6.Value
Shift1 = List12.Column(1)

strWhere = "Data![ShiftDate] = #" & Date1 & _
           "# AND Data![Shift] ='" & Shift1 & "'"

If DCount("*", "tblShifts", strWhere) > 0 Then
   ' record exist, simply open the form
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , strWhere

Else
   ' record does NOT exist, open form in add mode
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , , acFormAdd
   '
   ' setup the two default values
   Forms!Data!ShiftDate = Date1
   Forms!Data!Shift1 = Shift1

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 424 error is because using `=` needs an object on both sides of `=`, and `Data![shiftdate].Value` isn't an object.  I think what you need is:

```
Me.shiftdate = Date1
```